# Perl Scope Confusion with Format / Write

Tags: perl, scope, built-in

Why is `$var` unavailable (out of scope ?) to `write` when declared with `my`, if its scope is pretty much package-level ?

```
package ASDF;
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $var = 'foo';

format =
@<<<<< @>>>>>
'test : ', $var
.


sub test {
    say $var;
    write;
}


1;
```

Called with :

```
perl -wE 'use ASDF; ASDF::test();'
```

Produces :

```
foo
Variable "$var" is not available at ASDF.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $var in formline at ASDF.pm line 10.
test :
```

It appears otherwise available to `say` in the same scope ...

Replacing `my` with `our` fixes it :

```
foo
test :    foo
```

Why can't `write` pick-up on `$var` correctly ?
Is it a scope issue, or an issue with how Perl's `write` or `format` is implemented ?

Comment: Seems like formats don't properly close over lexical variables. This is the sort of error message I'd expect from `eval('$x')` where `$x` is a variable from some surrounding lexical scope that isn't used in the subroutine otherwise.

Comment: @toolic "*Replacing `my` with `our` fixes it :*"

Comment: Might I recommend Perl6::Form instead? (It's Perl6-like forms for Perl5.) It's a lot cleaner, and it avoids these problems

Comment: @melpomene Hey, I don't fully understand what it means to "properly close over lexical variables", but appreciate the quick response. I guess what might additionally aid my confusion is whether there's some technical or historical reason that format or write can't access my $var, as I would expect ? Or is my expectation unreasonable to begin with ? I assume someone must've decided that this quirk is not actually a bug ?

Comment: @ikegami The code I pasted is a derivation from a large Perl5 codebase ... at best I might be able to use Inline::Perl6 though !

Comment: I repeat: Perl6::Form is a module for Perl5

Comment: Formats are an ancient feature of Perl (older than local variables). My guess is no one has touched their code in 20 years. It looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Neat, if you want to post that as an answer I can accept it !
And thanks too, ikegami, I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of the [Perl format documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html) it says:

> Lexical variables (declared with "my") are not visible within a format unless the format is declared within the scope of the lexical variable.

Reading that would imply that what you are trying would work, but apparently lexically scoped variables work differently for `format` and `write` when called from outside of the package they where declared in. Also, all of the examples in the article use global variables...

[This more modern tutorial about format](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/08/use-formats-to-create-paginated-plaintext-reports/) repeats that you might run into trouble if you use lexically scoped variables (variables declared with `my`) because write picks the variables from the current package and, as stated in the comments of your question, was written in a time when Perl did not have the `my` keyword or lexical scoping.

The solutions the article offers:

> When you are ready to output some data, you use write. This design shows the age of formats since write doesn't take arguments to fill in the pictures. It uses the variables that are in scope.

```
our( $id, $name, $food, $amount ) = qw( 12 Buster Tuna 1.0 );
write();
```

> Formats are also a bit crufty because you don't pass arguments to write to fill in the pictures. Perl relies on variables with the specified names being in scope. You can use lexical variables, but they have to be in the same scope as the format definition, and they have to be in scope when you call write. It's impractical to do that with lexicals, so the most agile way involves localized package variables:

```
foreach my $record ( @cats ) {
    local( $id, $name, $food ) = @$record;
    write( $fh );
}
```

And also this advice in the wrap-up:

> - Use localized package variables to set data for the format

So, `our` and `local` seem to be the way to go if you want to keep using `format` and `write` in modern Perl.